# PHP Search in multiple tables using a keyword

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, Student and University.

I want to use a student number as a keyword to search for a record in Student and University tables. I tried using `%$keyword%` but it doesn't produce any result.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Student join University";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Use Union for search multiple table

```
$query = "(SELECT * FROM Student WHERE keywork LIKE '%".$keyword."%') 
           UNION
          (SELECT * FROM University WHERE keywork LIKE '%".$keyword."%')";

mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have put a condition ON for a join. 
Or you can use the below format

```
SELECT a.tutorial_id, a.tutorial_author, b.tutorial_count
     FROM tutorials_tbl a, tcount_tbl b
    WHERE a.tutorial_author = b.tutorial_author;
```

Read the following link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
$keyword = 111; // a random number
$str = "SELECT * FROM Student JOIN University ON Student.Universityid = University.id WHERE Student.id LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'";
```

it now shows records with Student IDs like 21112, 2111, 1112